# Run file before windows

Tags: batch-file, exe

I need to run a *.bat or *.exe file, but before windows start.

There are some programs to manage partitions that do this, for example "Acronis Disk Director Suite" allows you to create a new partition within Windows and then it asks you to restart the PC, when you do this you will see a script running and modifying your disk and then Windows starts and you have your new partition right there.

What I want is just to be able to run a *.bat or *.exe file the same way.

Comment: check `runonce` registry values: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310593

Comment: That's not a "script" running. It's a low-level boot loader that loads its own mini-operating system, performs the work, and then restores the Windows boot loader and restarts the system. It's a far cry from "running a *.bat or *.exe file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I am aware you can't run a windows file (.bat is a windows thing) without running some form of windows.
running an exe file is possible, but you would have to write it to interact with the hardware without any drivers.
if you just want it to run at startup of windows, google "windows reg startup" (no quotes).
or put the file in 
"C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"